# Regexp_replace explanation for PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, regexp-replace

I have checked the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html

But cannot for the life of me figure out why this part

```
r'(\d+)'
```

Leads to changing

```
'100-200'
```

to

```
'-----'
```

Anyone with good documentation on that? I believe the \d section looks for 0-9 but that's about as far as I get. I don't understand in which sequence you need to do what either.

Comment: Here not "\d" but "(\d+)", which means group of 0-9, not single digit. I.e. whole number "100000" will be replaced with "--".

Comment: Thanks Pasha. What about the 'r'? Where is that used for?

Comment: I am not familiar with Python; maybe, this is marker for regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

`\d` matches a digit i.e `0-9` and  `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed.

Column has value 100-200. according to above statement, 100 matches for the regex(`\d` will match each digit of 100 separately  but `+` matches 100 completely). So 100 will be replaced by `--.` In the same way 200 will be replaced by `--.` Finally we will have `-----` as column value.

**Brackets** are used if incase we want to group to capture later using index starting with 1.
Let's say we want to extract only 1st matched value in a column then in spark we can use regexp_extract as shown below:

```
df.select(regexp_extract('column', '(\d+)', 1)) # 1 is groupIndex
```

In python **Prefix r** used before a regular expression, it marks raw string. For example, '\n' is a new line whereas `r'\n'` means two characters: a backslash \ followed by n.
If you want to match "\n" and if you don't use r prefix then you have to escape \ like this `"\\n"` in your regex expression.

You can practice/test regex in this [website](https://regex101.com/), you will get real time explanation about what's happening in background. You can go through this simple [cheatsheet](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285).

Comment: Thank you Mohana. You speak of "+ matches the previous token between one and unlimited times", what about the brackets? You need to include that when you do the '+'? Also, thank you for the link :)

Comment: Brackets are not required unless you want to group.  Let's say you want only first 100 from 100-200 then you can group using brackets in regex (\d)+. Now you can access group values using index starting with 1.  spark exapmles: regexp_extract('column', '(\d+)', 1) --> This will give output as 100.